# add bluetooth plugin in Flutter

Tags: plugins, bluetooth, flutter

I need to add Bluetooth to a Flutter app. I've searched for it in the entire network, but couldn't find any answer.

Is there a stable plug-in to use Bluetooth with Flutter for both Android and IOS?
And is there any code examples available ?

Thank you very much for the provided answers!

Comment: this might help  https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue

Comment: I tried flutter_blue example code but I can't connect with any device

Answer (score 1):

[You can check flutter package for bluetooth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_blue) 
This might help. Have a nice time.

Answer (score 0):

You can check article [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-adding-bluetooth-functionality-1b9715ccc698).Some of the responses say that the script works, and the contributor is quiet active to help difficulties. But the plugin will only work for Android. Good day.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.